# DB query explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am unable to understand how the following query brings the appropriate result please explain me this

Consider the following relation schema for an airline database.

```
customer(id, name, age, gender)
onFlight(id, flightNo, flightDate)
flightInfo(flightNo, fromCity, toCity, startTime, duration
```

. Flights (flightNo, flightDate) on which there are at least two customers

```
SELECT f1.flightNo, f1.flightDate
FROM onFlight as f1, onFlight as f2
WHERE f1.flightNo = f2.flightNo AND f1.flightDate=f2.flightDate AND __________________ f1.id <> f2.id
```

can i write this query instead of...

```
select flightNo, flightDate count(id) from onFlight groupBy(id) having count(id)>1
```

Comment: Is this homework? This will currently generate a staggered list of flights (f1 IDs: 1, 3, 5, 7) (f2 IDs: 2, 4, 6, 8), is this what you wish to achieve?

Comment: No, home work i am learning sql my own, but i was facing trouble understanding this query that's why i put it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  f1.flightNo, f1.flightDate
FROM    onFlight as f1, onFlight as f2
WHERE   f1.flightNo = f2.flightNo
        AND f1.flightDate = f2.flightDate
        AND f1.id <> f2.id
```

This builds cross-joins (all possible combinations) of all flights for each `flightNo / flightDate` pairs possible, this selects all non-matching records.

This is not the most efficient way, since it will return all duplicates if there are striclty more than two customers.

The more efficient way would be:

```
SELECT  flightNo, flightDate
FROM    onFlight
GROUP BY
        flightNo, flightDate
HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2
```

You can replace `2` with any other number here.

Comment: What should be alternate than please suggest me ..or write the query

Comment: in you abve query what the count does, does it count the total no no which are grouped by(flightNo, flightDate)

Answer (score 1):

It could be more effective:

```
SELECT f1.flightNo, f1.flightDate, COUNT(*)
FROM onFlight AS f1, onFlight AS f2
WHERE f1.flightNo = f2.flightNo AND f1.flightDate=f2.flightDate 
GROUP BY f1.flightNo, f1.flightDate
HAVING COUNT(*)>=2
```